# 766 versus 666 Permissions on an Upload Directory

Tags: php, upload, permissions

Is 766 permissions okay for a directory where my website users can upload images to?

I using 766 because when I set the directory to 666, the script returns an error and the file is not uploaded. Please is there any explanation for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 755 is the way to go because the User need the **execute flag** to enter the directory.

### Edit

Same issue with 766 if the **Web user** is either **Group** or **Others**. 6 = read/write and lack the execute flag.

So 7**66** wont work if the web server is not the owner of the directory.

Comment: Sorry  I meant 766 not 755. Wiill edit this post shortly

Comment: So from a  web server security point of view, is 766 safe for me to allow my website users to upload files to? This assumes I am performing other checks on the file itself

Comment: The 66 part is useless and is the same as 00. As only the User (with 7) is allowed to enter the directory. 755, will work because 5 allow read + execute (entrance) to the directory.